# Grid Flow is always dense even when omitted?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow), if `grid-auto-flow` is not specified or only specified to be row or column and `dense` is omitted.. it should be set to `sparse` and the DOM should be respected and gaps earlier than the first element that could be filled will not be filled.

My code appears to default to dense. How could I force it to act sparse?

I also tried setting the auto flow to row or column instead of not setting it at all but that didn't work either.

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.first {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box first" style="background-color: #E53935">FIRST</div>
  <div class="box second" style="background-color: #D81B60">SECOND</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #8E24AA">THIRD</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #5E35B1">FOURTH</div>
  <!--         <div class="box" style="background-color: #3949AB">FIFTH</div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color: #1E88E5">SIXTH</div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color: #00ACC1">SEVENTH</div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color: #00897B">EIGHTH</div> -->
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/bigpaloma/pen/MWqVVeN?editors=1100)

Below you can find the desired result of the code above. I have hardcoded the individual box placements inside the grid, how could this be achieved by only setting the first box like in the snippet above.

**While hardcoding i have discovered that the sparse property only gets ignored on the first box IF `grid-row` is set. If `grid-row` is not set at all the grid behaves `sparse`, otherwise `dense`. Also if you place the second box after the first one in `grid-column: 4/5;` and dont set `grid-row`, the following boxes do not act `dense`. Further proving this. Please feel free to try for yourself**

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.first {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box first" style="background-color: #E53935">FIRST</div>
  <div class="box second" style="background-color: #D81B60">SECOND</div>
  <div class="box third" style="background-color: #8E24AA">THIRD</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #5E35B1">FOURTH</div>
  <!--         <div class="box" style="background-color: #3949AB">FIFTH</div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color: #1E88E5">SIXTH</div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color: #00ACC1">SEVENTH</div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color: #00897B">EIGHTH</div> -->
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/bigpaloma/pen/eYLjpMo?editors=1100)

Comment: Also tested on firefox and works the same

Comment: Interesting behaviour, I didn't know this! Looks like you've solved your question and have the behaviour you're after? If so move that portion out into an answer to your own question. If not edit the question to ask for an explanation/make it clearer what you're after :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**While hardcoding i have discovered that the sparse property only gets ignored on the first box IF grid-row is set. If grid-row is not set at all the grid behaves sparse, otherwise dense. Also if you place the second box after the first one in grid-column: 4/5; and dont set grid-row, the following boxes do not act dense. Further proving this. Please feel free to try for yourself**

Answer (score 0):

The grid is behaving as intended, so let's break down what's happening

This declaration actually does nothing, as `row` is the initial value for `grid-auto-flow` out of the box:

```css
grid-auto-flow: row;
```

So we're placing items on our grid in rows, with a "sparse" algorithm:

> If the dense keyword is omitted, a "sparse" algorithm is used, where the placement algorithm only ever moves "forward" in the grid when placing items, never backtracking to fill holes. This ensures that all of the auto-placed items appear "in order", even if this leaves holes that could have been filled by later items. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow#dense)

So you're thinking that the sparse algorithm should give each box a fresh row, which makes sense - it's called "sparse" and you've made four rows.

How it works is that sparse doesn't *backtrack* to fill previous free spaces, it just goes forwards. This is entirely different to looking forward to see if there's lots of free space.

What your grid here will do is place the boxes along in a row because they all fit, and dense/sparse will not matter at all because we've already placed all of our boxes on the first row.

If you want the boxes to get a row each then the `column` grid flow might work for you:

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #E53935">FIRST</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #D81B60">SECOND</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #8E24AA">THIRD</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: #5E35B1">FOURTH</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for correcting my question.

Comment: First of all thanks for correcting my question. The problem i have with this is not that each box is not taking up a column. I am in the clear about the grid-auto-flow property. My grid is set to row and i have 5 boxes, 2 rows and 4 columns. At default my grid should have 1 2 3 4 on the first row and 5 on the second row. if i now manually put the first box to start at grid line 1 the first row should have 1 2 3 and the second row 4 5. Only when  i set it to dense should the second box be in first place and then follows 1 3 4 and the 5 on the second row. but my code acts dense even when i omit.

Comment: My desired result would be. I leave my code as is and the first row contains 1 and 2 starting at the third column. second row 3 and 4.

Comment: correction for my second comment: second line is taking up a row not taking up a column.

Comment: @FurkanSengün Can you please add this information to your question by editing the question, try and sketch up a quick image of how you want things to look and I'll update my answer for you!

Comment: please find the updadet question above:) as you can see the desired result gets achieved by not settin grid-row on the first box. as to why this is happening maybe you know more!